# Internationalization in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, properties, internationalization

I have a springBoot 2.4.0 app, with this piece of code in the controller:

```
String defaultLocation =
                messages.getMessage("home.default.location", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

In the application I see the messages from the properties loaded correctly with the messages, and no error, but in the log I see this error:

```
14:43:41.168 [http-nio-7080-exec-13] WARN  o.s.c.s.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.refreshProperties 445 - Could not parse properties file [messages_en.properties]
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at java.base/java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:229)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:500)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:415)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:378)
    at org.springframework.util.DefaultPropertiesPersister.load(DefaultPropertiesPersister.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.loadProperties(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.java:495)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.refreshProperties(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.java:440)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.getProperties(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.resolveCodeWithoutArguments(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.java:186)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessageInternal(AbstractMessageSource.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:153)
    at com.bonanza.controller.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:46)
```

this is my config class:

```
@Configuration
public class I18NConfig {

    private final Environment env;

    public I18NConfig(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        
            resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        

        resourceBundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"); // Set the UTF-8 encoding
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setCacheSeconds(1);
        return resourceBundleMessageSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a warning and confirm that you have proper properties file as property_file_name_en.properties ans so on.

Comment: Otherwise… could you provide us your respective properties file here or the real file e. g. in any Github project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource
```

instead of

```
org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource
```

configuration like this:

```
   <bean name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
    <property name="basename"> 
        <value>classpath*:i18n/messages</value> 
    </property> 
</bean>
```

or this:

```
 @Bean
 public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10); //reload messages every 10 seconds
        return messageSource;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change in your bean definition like this ...remove cache seconds and use setUSeCodeAsDefaultMessage() and give it a try.Also recheck you properties file definitions and naming references.

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        
            resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        

        resourceBundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return resourceBundleMessageSource;
    }
```